Cyclic hexagon with alternate sides equal variation: second points of intersection of circumcircles of isosceles triangles

A hexagon $\text{ABCDEF}$ is inscribed in a circle of radius $R$ and centre $\text{O}$ such that $\overline{\text{AB}}= \overline{\text{CD}}= \overline{\text{EF}}= R$. Prove that the second points of intersections of the circumcircles of $\triangle \text{OBC}$, $\triangle \text{ODE}$, $\triangle \text{OFA}$ form an equilateral triangle of side length $R$.

I noticed that the inner triangle inverts to the triangle formed with the circle intercepting $\overline{\text{BC}}$, $\overline{\text{DE}}$, $\overline{\text{FA}}$ on its sides. Allegedly, the centre $\text{O}$ of such a circle is called 'isodynamic point'. I would like someone to solve it without inversion if possible. (A solution with inversion is also okay. Also, please prove any properties of stuff like isodynamic points if you're gonna use them).

This question is very interesting. Could you tell where this question is taken from?

Umm, I'm not sure about the source myself. It was given to me by an associate. I guess he found it on AOPS or somewhere. This is definitely a problem from a past Olympiad.


$$\begin{align}
\angle FZE&=360-\angle OZF-\angle OZE\\
&=(180-\angle OZF)+(180-\angle OZE)\\
&=\angle OAF+\angle ODE\\
&=90-\frac{\angle AOF}{2}+90-\frac{\angle EOD}{2}\\
&=90+\frac{\angle BOC}{2}\\
&=180-\angle BCO\\
&=\angle BXO\\
\\
\angle AXO&=180-\angle OFA\\
&=180-\angle FAO\\
&=\angle OZF
\end{align}$$

[The following part is not shown in the diagram]
Suppose we pick up the equilateral triangle $\triangle OFE$ (with $Z$
inside it) and place it, point-by-point, over $\triangle AOB$.
Let us assume that $Z$ and $X$ do not coincide.
Since $\angle AXO=\angle OZF$, so $A,O,X,Z$ are now cyclic.
Since $\angle FZE=\angle BXO$, so $B,O,X,Z$ are now cyclic.
But two circles can’t meet at 3 points ($O,X,Z$)! So, our assumption
must have been wrong, and $X$ and $Z$ are actually coinciding.
So, $XO=FZ$ and $AX=OZ$

Coming back to the original diagram, $XO=FZ$, $AX=OZ$ and $AO=OF$ prove that $\triangle AXO$ and $\triangle OZF$ are congruent. Thus, $\angle XOA=\angle ZFO$.
$$\begin{align}
\angle XOA&=\angle ZFO\\
\therefore \angle XFA&=\angle ZFO\\
\therefore \angle OFA&=\angle XFZ\\
\therefore \angle AXO&=\angle XOZ\\
\therefore AO&=XZ\\
\end{align}$$
Thus, $XZ=AO=R$. Similarly, we can show that $XY$ and $YZ$ are also equal to $R$, proving that $\triangle XYZ$ is equilateral with side length $R$.

Interesting fact: Relative position of $X$ in $\triangle AOB$, $Y$ in $\triangle DCO$, $Z$ in $\triangle OFE$ and $O$ in $\triangle ZXY$ are same.

Geogebra link, showing the intermediate diagrams used in the solution process.

Excellent solution, a very elegant solution to a nice problem.

@SidN Thanks for your kind remark:)

The problem is somewhat difficult and I give here a partial answer. Nothing is said about the sides $BC, DE$ and $FA$ which can be of arbitrary length but such that the sum of the angles at the common vertex $O$ is equal to $180$ degrees. Here I solve the problem with the six equal sides which gives a regular hexagon for which expressions in terms of the radius $R$ are known.
It is known that each side is equal to $R$. Calculation gives as centers of the circumcircles $\left(\dfrac R2,\dfrac{R\sqrt3}{6}\right),\space \left(-\dfrac R2,\dfrac{R\sqrt3}{6}\right), \space\left(0,\dfrac{R\sqrt3}{3}\right)$ and radius $r=\dfrac{R\sqrt3}{3}$
Consequently the circumcircles have equations
$$\left(x-\frac R2\right)^2+\left(y-\dfrac{R\sqrt3}{6}\right)^2=\frac{R^2}{3}\\\left(x+\frac R2\right)^2+\left(y-\dfrac{R\sqrt3}{6}\right)^2=\frac{R^2}{3}\\x^2+\left(y+\dfrac{R\sqrt3}{3}\right)^2=\frac{R^2}{3}$$ Intersections of these circles yield points $P,Q,S$ whose coordinates are calculated $$P=\left(0,\frac{R\sqrt3}{3}\right),\space Q=\left(-\frac R2,-\frac{R\sqrt3}{6}\right),\space S=\left(\frac R2,-\frac{R\sqrt3}{6}\right)$$ and it is verified that $\overline{PQ}=\overline{QS}=\overline{PS}=R$.
Note.-It seems to me that the equilateral triangle in question is the same for arbitrary sides $BC, DE$ and $FA$, provided that the corresponding triangles are separated by angles of $60$ degrees in the origine. I leave here my partial answer.


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

-1 You have proven this for one specific case, and not explained how to deal with the general case.

@CalvinLin: So you think you have the right to put a downvote on an answer that was explicitly biased but correct when no one had yet been able to give an answer?

1/ I downvote on wrong answers, independently of whether there are other correct answers posted. 2/ Soham posted a correct answer, which I upvoted. 3/ I get that we disagree on "does solving a specific case means the solution is "wrong"(my interpretation) or that the solution is "explicitly biased but correct"(your interpretation)? I think it is "wrong" because it gives others a false sense of what a solution entails. Ultimately, we have our own opinions about this (and other things), and will not agree on everything.
